# .NET DateTime.ToString() - Default Format Setting

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, cultureinfo, date-formatting

Is the default format of ToString dependent on anything server related?  Here's the issue:  I'm testing and have tested an application on my local machine and ToString(), by default, is returning in a format of "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", however on our server it appears to be returning as "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" which the consuming application is not expecting and causing errors.

```
Dim uvExpireDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
Dim token = String.Format(fmtString, uvExpireDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString(), [various other params])
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formatting depends on the default Culture defined on the server.

If you want a specific Culture to apply, you need to use an overload that takes an `IFormatProvider`, or set the current thread `Culture` and `UICulture` to the wanted Culture.

`InvariantCulture` is a Culture that represents no specific culture but is based on `en-US`, so may be suitable for your use:

```
uvExpireDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

So, the whole line would be:

```
Dim token = String.Format(fmtString, _ 
            uvExpireDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), _ 
            [various other params])
```

Comment: +1 And the light bulb flips on.  It's only our Canadian clients that are having issues :)  Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a complex issue. CultureInfo is based on the machine's language, and not on the machine's formatting options. These are two separate things and part of the reason why the Windows/Net dichotomy causes so much hell in this area. For example, I'm in Australia. My date formats are set to d/MM/yyyy. In the "Format" drop down list, it says "English (Australia)". But, my language is en-US because there is no language for en-AU. There's only 1 language installed on my computer and I can check this by going to "Additional settings..." under "Region".

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
    var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(culture);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

Comment: This code should spit out a date formatted in Australian format, but it doesn't. The output was: en-AU
3/4/2016 10:54:28 AM (The date and month are around the wrong way)

Comment: The debugger tells me that current culture is FullDateTimePattern = "dddd, d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt", and yet ToString() gives me something completely different.

Comment: In other words ToString() on DateTime is neither picking up the formats from my regional settings, or from the formats in the CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture object.

Comment: But, this code DOES work:                 CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
                var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(culture);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

Comment: Output: en-AU
4/03/2016 11:07:42 AM which is correct.

Comment: The moral of my story is that .Net does not reliably pick up the correct culture from your regional settings. As far as I know, you have to explicitly set it. Furthermore, there's no way to get that culture, because if you get the culture, you're just going to get the machine's language, which is most likely going to be en-US despite any formatting options you might have.

Answer (score 0):

The computer "Region and Language Options" (Control Panel) specify the Date Format.

You can hardcode the date format:
For Example:

```
uvExpireData.ToString(@"yyyyMMdd HH.mm.ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) shows how to use code to set the culture if you can't change it on the server (Law of Unintended Consequences might apply):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

public class FormatDate
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
      // Sets the CurrentCulture property to U.S. English.
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
      // Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
      // and the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
      Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d"));

      // Creates a CultureInfo for German in Germany.
      CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
      // Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
      // and the CultureInfo.
      Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", ci));
   }
}
```